# Pass a lazy value as a function or method parameter without evaluating it?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I have a `lazy val`, but when I pass it to another method it is getting evaluated before that method needs to use it:

```
lazy val i = { print("evaluation happened!"); 42 }
def willEvaluate(n: Int) = println("hello")
willEvaluate(i) // Prints "evaluation happened! hello"
```

I tried marking `n` as lazy, but it doesn't compile:

```
def willEvaluate(lazy n: Int) = ...
def willEvaluate(n: lazy Int) = ...
// Both fail to compile with error: identifier expected but 'lazy' found.
```

How do you pass a lazy value into another method without it being evaluated?

Answer (score 4):

Function signatures definitely would look prettier if you could use the `lazy` keyword in them, but it appears that is not possible. However, you can do what you want by declaring the parameter as a [by-name parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html):

```
def wontEvaluate(n: => Int) = println("hello")
```

Then when you pass your lazy value in it won't get evaluated unless it is actually used.

```
lazy val i = { print("evaluation happened! "); 42 }    
def willEvaluate(n: => Int) = println(n)
wontEvaluate(i)  // Prints "hello"
willEvaluate(i)  // Prints "evaluation happened! 42"
```